# How to SFTP into IBM Cloud Object Storage

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-storage

I am looking to use sftp to upload files into IBM cloud object storage. Similar to: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/infrastructure/objectstorage-swift/connect-object-storage-using-sftp.html

Which is for openstack swift. Is this possible? I could not find documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to connect to IBM cloud object storage by SFTP protocol similar that the Object Storage OpenStack Swift because the sftp port can not connect to the IBM cloud object storage host.

Another way to connect and upload files into IBM cloud object storage is through the Amazon S3 protocol.

Below I leave a link in which you will find the necessary steps to connect to IBM cloud object storage:
https://developer.ibm.com/cloudobjectstorage/tutorials/using-desktop-client-ibm-cloud-object-storage-public-service-cyberduck-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this documentation on using s3fs to mount the bucket as storage https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-s3fs

Additionally, I had to install s3fs (it is not detailed in the guide) as it was failing to find the command. After that you have to configure sftp in the server and you should be able to access the mounted directory.

I personally used the following image https://hub.docker.com/r/atmoz/sftp/ (shout out to the owner) to set the container with the configured sftp and then you can move the files from the sftp folder into the mounted bucket in order to transfert them to ibm cloud.